# Free statistics program to evaluate measurement data?

Tags: resource-recommendations, error-analysis, statistics, software, data-analysis

Does anyone know of a good free statistics program where I can, for example, enter measured values and their respective uncertainty and the program will then spit out the variance weighted means for me (this is extremely tiring every time with the calculator)?

Comment: Perhaps more suited to [softwarerecs.se].  That said have you considered using a spreadsheet - there are plenty of open source ones of excellent quality and with statistical functions.  [Libre Office](https://www.libreoffice.org/) has a spreadsheet called LibreCalc.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21313/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525215/44126, and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a very simple task to do

- with a spreadsheet, like LibreOffice or the one coming with Google suit (free).
- (if you're familiar with just a little programming) with a very simple script in Python, R, Octave (free), Matlab (licensed), or whatever programming language you like.

If you provide an example of a file containing your data to be used as the input of the computations, it would be possible to write that simple script.

Answer (score 2):

The single best free software for statistics is [R](https://www.r-project.org/). It is now the de facto standard for new statistics. When researchers develop and implement a new method they generally do so in R first. As a result there is a huge base of packages available to handle any statistical task.

In my experience any statistical problem I have had has been solved with the following steps in R:

1. find a package which does what you need
2. load the package
3. feed your data into the package (this is often the most difficult step)
4. run the package